# Visual Studio - SDL2 - entrypoint not found in libpng 16

Tags: visual-studio, sdl-2, sdl-image

While I was working with SDL2 in Visual Studio, I found a error as soon as I wanted to load a png.

The Error says: 'Entrypoint "inflateValidate" not found in "C:...\bin\Debug\x64\libpng16-16.dll"

My Compiler also outputs this:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAC2072B10 (ntdll.dll) in SDL_Project.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
'SDL_Project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Robin Sucur\source\repos\SDL-Project-master1\bin\Debug\x64\zlib1.dll'
'SDL_Project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Robin Sucur\source\repos\SDL-Project-master1\bin\Debug\x64\libpng16-16.dll'

Does someone know a solution? I have searched but found nothing...

Comment: What dlls you have? `inflate` sounds like zlib, and SDL_image binary distribution have `zlib1.dll`.

Comment: i have all the nessecary dlls - also the zlib1